# Bounty sign doesn't appear in the new front page

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, homepage

Consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118847/c-tangent-binormal-and-other-shader-related-things), which has been assigned a bounty of +500 for over 20 minutes, but the <kbd>+500</kbd> sign never appears in the new home page.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch, my detached/cachable model was not caching the bounty fields.

Will be fixed in the next deploy